# Number of n X n binary matrices with every 1 adjacent to some zero and every 0 adjacent to some one, horizontally or vertically.

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, binary

I came across this integer sequence: [A133792](http://oeis.org/A133792).
It represents the number of $n\times n$ binary matrices with every 1 adjacent to some zero and every 0 adjacent to some one, horizontally or vertically.

Now, assuming there exists a way except for bruteforce, how would I go about to calculate this number? (As enumerating valid matrices one-by-one seems hardly feasible, given the fast growing nature of the sequence.)

For even ns, I think the problem is related to tiling patterns of dominoes on checkerboards (or at least, using two colored dominoes would ensure that the adjacency constraint won't be violated).

Comment: Unsure about how to use dominos because it could be cases where you have way more 0s than 1s and vice versa. It would be a very small subset of the possible combinations